# Merge statement in Sql server with target table as existing table in Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

QUESTION:I have table ARMS.RefRollno in my database and with roll no and rank now i have query which is returning a dataset of roll and rank .If my table contains that row then i need to update it and if not that i want to insert a new row in respect to that roll no.

```
    create table #temp
    (
      ROLLNO varchar(100),
      Ranking varchar(100),
      TestRecID varchar(100)
    )
    INSERT INTO #temp (ROLLNO, Ranking,TestRecID) EXEC [ARMS].[GetStudentResultForUpdateRank] '412'

   MERGE ARMS.RefRollno AS C
    USING #temp AS CT
    ON C.TestRecID = CT.TestRecID
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET
    C.RefRank = CT.Ranking      
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT (TestRecId,RefRollNo, RefRank,IsActive,CreatedDate)
    VALUES (CT.TestRecID,CT.ROLLNO,CT.Ranking, 1,getdate());
    drop table #temp
```

> Here ARMS.RefRollno is my existing table in Database.
>   Any Help is appreciated.

```
    ** Error by Sql Server:Incorrect syntax near 'MERGE'.**
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Sql server is not allowing me to use target table as existing one.

Comment: @user1598415 - no, you've misdiagnosed the issue. A merge always targets an existing table.

Comment: Please provide full code that reproduces the problem. Works fine for me. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/02ad1). Also check that you are definitely on 2008 not a previous version with `SELECT @@VERSION`

Comment: @MartinSmith :Sir Please check I had put the whole code

Comment: What does `SELECT @@VERSION` return?

Comment: @MartinSmith it returns 'Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4290.0 (X64)   Aug  5 2013 12:40:54   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
EXEC [ARMS].[GetStudentResultForUpdateRank] '412'
```

To

```
EXEC [ARMS].[GetStudentResultForUpdateRank] '412';
```

(Note addition of trailing semicolon).

This only seems to be necessary if the database is in an earlier compatibility mode than 2008.